# Reloading iframe from Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">4</div>
</div>
```

If i replaced the numbers in the tabs with youtube embeded iframes video, How can i refresh tabs everytime i move between tabs? Because if i played video in first tab then moved to the next tab, the first tab would still play and consume the visitor internet

Comment: You can utilize the events that fire when switching tabs: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events

Comment: @J.Titus tried to use it but the entire code didn't work, Is there is something i missed?

Comment: @J.Titus Fixed it, But that didn't refresh the iframe